# Convert cmd to powershell query

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

Please help:

CMD command:

```
C:/abc.exe” “MyPC” /RFS “script.rfs
```

Please help me in converting this to powershell.

I tried to read the documentation but couldn’t find anything useful.
Any sort of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try : $parameters = '“C:/abc.exe” “MyPC” /RFS “script.rfs”'; c:\abc.exe $parameters

Comment: @jdweng Didn’t work. Thanks though.

Comment: What error did you get?  Try without double quotes : $parameters = 'C:/abc.exe MyPC /RFS script.rfs'; c:\abc.exe $parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the call statement  (alias &).

```
& "C:\abc.exe" "MyPC" /RFS "script.rfs"
```

I'm not sure about the double quotes, especially around abc.exe.  It depends on what role those double quotes are playing in CMD.  One of the features of the ampersand construct is that it prevents the usual parsing of parameters to the initial command.